# Making sure that the user includes an '@' symbol in their input

Tags: python

I would like to validate the data that the user has entered in my program (an email address). If the user enters an '@' symbol, the program should accept it. If it does not, the program should loop and ask for the email again. So far I have attempted to do this, but the program loops for every character that has been entered:

```
emailright = True

while emailright == True:    
    email = input("Please enter your email address")
    character = ("@")
    for character in email:
        if character == '@':
            print("Your email address had been registered")
            emailright = True
        else:
            print("invalid email address, please re-enter")
            emailright = False
```

The while loop and everything inside it has also been indented.
Thank you!

Comment: `if '@' in email:`?

Comment: You need to replace `for character in email:` with `if character in email`, also `emailright` should start as `False` at the top

Comment: Note that simply having an `@` doth not necessarily constitute a valid email address. Why re-invent the wheel? http://emailregex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there are many better email validation methods, this implements your logic much more concisely:

```
email = input("Please enter your email address")
while '@' not in email:    
    email = input("invalid email address, please re-enter")
print("Your email address had been registered")
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
import re


is_email_valid = None


while is_email_valid is None:
    email = input("Please enter your email address")
    is_email_valid = re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$', email)
    if is_email_valid:
        print("Your email address had been registered")
    else:
        print("invalid email address, please re-enter")
```

this is a site where I extracted the regex from:

http://emailregex.com/

Answer (score -3):

```
while True:    
    email = input("Please enter your email address")
    if '@' in email:
        break
```

Or:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email

Comment: Not sure why this has so many down-votes when it does precisely what the OP asked.